# What's a formula for a graph like this?

Tags: graphing-functions

I'm trying to find a method to turn a value (that can reach a maximum of N) into a percentage. But I don't want it to be linear, I need it to be non-linear like the in this graph:

[graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/upME5.png)

Comment: Do you really mean logarithmic or do you just mean nonlinear?

Comment: Oh sorry I meant non-linear.

Comment: There are a lot of options, depending on how you want the curve to be shaped. If you're fine with a quadratic, something like $y = 100-\frac{100}{N^2}(x-N)^2$ would work. See [this graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/2tuzefhdsa).

Comment: Thanks that was quick :) . It's for a programming method so the best is the one that requires least amount of calculations

Comment: Could also go with $y = 100\sqrt{\frac{x}{N}}$, [here's a graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/p3reytvfzi) of that. Fewer calculations, curvature's a bit different.

Comment: I was specifically looking for a method that's the most linear in the early part of the graph, so I think the first one is best

Comment: Actually no I think the second one works best. Thanks :)

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, any function that fits the following qualifications will be somewhat similar to the graph:

1. Increasing from $x = 0$ to $x = N$
2. [Concave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concave_function) from $x = 0$ to $x = N$
3. $f(0) = 0$ and $f(N) = 100$

To keep things simple, we can use a function that is twice-differentiable. Then, we need $f'(x) > 0$ for $x\in (0,N)$, and $f''(x) < 0$ for $x\in (0,N)$.

There are a lot of options out there for functions that fit these requirements, but two easy ones to implement are

- $f(x) = 100-\frac{100}{N^2}(x-N)^2$
- $f(x) = 100\sqrt{\frac{x}{N}}$

Comment: @OP The gamma correction for color adjustment is a typical non linear function, i.e. $\left(\frac xN\right)^\gamma$. Here we just flip it and scale it so that $f(0)=0$ and $f(N)=100$, so it become $100\left(1-\big(1-\frac xN\big)^\gamma\right)$. https://www.desmos.com/calculator/787gqjm0ov

Answer (score 0):

Set $$f(x)=\frac{200 x}{N}-\frac{100 x^2}{N^2}$$
where $N$ is the maximum $x$ value.

For instance, if you want $N=150$ you set
$$f(x)=\frac{4 x}{3}-\frac{x^2}{225}$$
and get a curve like the following

[image]